# Ajax loading of scripts (using jQuery) from CDN is't working

Tags: ajax, jquery, amazon-cloudfront

In my Javascript heavy Web app, I have some scripts that are loaded in the source HTML with  tags, and others that I load as needed using jQuery's ajax method.

I am in the process of relocating most of my app's static assets to a CDN (I'm using AWS Cloudfront). My dynamic loads no longer work. The jQuery Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url, 
    dataType: 'script',
    async: true,
    success: function (content) {
        ....
```

triggers the success function, but the content is empty.

I'm wondering if this is because such a request violates the Browser's security model for cross-site scripting. If that's the case, is there to load scripts dynamically from a CDN?  Ahhh... I am NOT presently using a CNAME alias for the cloudfront host. Would doing so solve this problem?

Comment: What are the URLs you are using?

Comment: I haven't yet done so, but I am pretty sure that I need to set up a CNAME with my DNS that points to my Cloudfront, AND to tell Cloudfront about the CNAME so it can serve the requests from my repository.

Comment: Well, I have a CNAME set up, but as it is for a subdomain, it didn't help because the Same Origin Policy doesn't permit loading scripts from subdomains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, it is the cross-site scripting security preventing this.

You're able to use the [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) method to load it from an external domain (or internal).

Comment: jQuery.getScript uses jQuery.ajax, so I'm still confronting the same issue.